# Confused at control flow of async/await of c#

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm learning about async/await ,and get confused on the explaination of the await of [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await):"***The await operator suspends execution until the work of the GetByteArrayAsync method is complete. In the meantime, control is returned to the caller of GetPageSizeAsync***"

What i don't understand is,what does it mean "returned"? At first,i believed when a thread(let's say, the UI thread) reaches the "await" keyword, system will create a new thread(or get a thread from threadPool) to execute the rest of codes,and UI thread can return to the caller method and execute the rest.

But now i know that "await" will never create thread.

I write a demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().M1();
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:8");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

class Test
{
    public async void M1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:1");
        var t = M2();
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:3");
        await t;
    }
    public async Task<string> M2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:2");
        string rs = await M3();//when the thread reaches here,why don't it return to M1 and execute the STEP:3 ??
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:7");
        return rs;

    }

    public async Task<string> M3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:4");
        var rs = Task.Run<string>(() => {
            Thread.Sleep(3000);//simulate some work that takes 3 seconds
            Console.WriteLine("STEP:6");
            return "foo";
        });
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:5");
        return await rs;
    }
}
```

this demo prints some labels representing the execute flow,which i thought it would be

STEP:1

STEP:2

STEP:3

STEP:4

STEP:5

STEP:6

STEP:7

STEP:8

(from 1 to 8 in order),

but the actual result is :
[Figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzfRY.png)

STEP:1

STEP:2

STEP:4

STEP:5

STEP:3

STEP:8

STEP:6

STEP:7

If like MSDN's explaination, control is returned to M1 and print the "STEP 3", absolutely i'm wrong,So what's going on exactly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Be clear - `async` "just" changes what you can write inside a method. `await` doesn't *start* anything happening. You always pass something to `await` that represents *work that has already been started*. The how and why that the work got started is *not* the concern of `await`.

Comment: I've posted *quite a long* answer and its quite wordy. However, I felt it was all necessary to address your question and confusion. Let me know if you see issues with it. I'll probably return soon and add links to further reading also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just to get it out of the way, there's no guarantee that, at any particular `await` point we're going to do *anything* beyond carrying on with the rest of the code. However, in the sample in MSDN and your own example, we will always wait at each of the `await` points.

So, we reach some point where we have `await z` and we've decided that we're going to wait. This means a) That `z` hasn't Completed yet (whatever it means for `z` to be complete isn't something we care about at this moment in time) and b) That we have no useful work to do ourselves, at the moment.

Hopefully, from the above, you can see why "creating a new thread" or anything like it isn't necessary, because like I just said, there's no useful work to do.

Before we return control from our method though, we're going to enqueue a *continuation*. The `async` machinery is able to express "*when* z has completed, arrange for the rest of *this* method to continue from our `await` point".

Here, things like synchronization contexts and `ConfigureAwait` become relevant. The thread that we're running on (and that we're about to relinquish control of) may be "special" in some way. It may be the UI thread. It may currently have exclusive access to some resources (think ASP.Net pre-Core Request/Response/Session objects).

If that's so, hopefully the system providing the special-ness has installed a synchronization context, and it's via that that we also are able to obtain "*when* we resume execution of this method, we need to have the same special circumstances we previously had". So e.g. we're able to resume running our method *back on the UI thread*.

By default, without a synchronization context, a thread pool thread will be found to run our continuation.

Note that, if a method contains multiple `await`s that require waiting, after that first wait, we'll be running as a chained continuation. Our *original* caller got their context back the *first* time we `await`ed.

---

In your sample, we have three `await` points and all three of them *will* wait and cause us to relinquish control back to our caller (and we don't have multiple `await`s in a single method to worry about either). All of these awaits are, at the end of the day, waiting for that `Thread.Sleep` to finish (poor form in modern `async` code which should use `TaskDelay` instead). So any `Console.WriteLine`s appearing after an `await` *in that method* will be delayed.

However, `M1` is `async void`, something best avoided outside of event handlers. `async void` methods are problematic because they offer no means of determining *when* they've completed.

`Main` calls `M1` which prints `1` and then calls `M2`. `M2` prints `2` and then calls `M3`. `M3` prints `4`, creates a new `Task`, prints `5` and only then can *it* relinquish control. It's at this point that it creates a `TaskCompletionSource` that will represent its eventual completion, obtain the `Task` from it, and return that.

Notice that it's only when the call to `M3` *returns* that we hit the `await` in `M2`. We also have to wait here so we do almost the same as `M3` and return a `Task`.

Now `M1` finally has a `Task` that it can `await` on. But before it does that, it prints `3`. It returns control to `Main` which now prints `8`.

Eons later, the `Thread.Sleep` in `rs` in `M3` finishes running, and we print `6`. `M3` marks its returned `Task` as complete, has no more work to do, and so exits with no further continuations arranged.

`M2` can now resume and its `await` and print `6`. Having done that, its `Task` is complete and `M1` can finally resume and print `7`.

`M1` doesn't have a `Task` to mark as complete because it was `async void`.

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: @Oliver - this was about the fourth of fifth answer I tried to write for this question and even then it took serious revisions before I posted it. There were so many subtleties worth exploring here.

Comment: But most of those subtitles are irrelevant to the code at hand, and the question asked about it.  There's no need to do an entire `await` tutorial to answer the question asked.  And if that's what a reader wants, lots of those tutorials already exist.

Comment: @Servy - well, they seemed to care about the UI thread, mentioning it several times, which is why I wanted to discuss synchronization contexts, as an example.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever What a nice explanation! You know what, when i read "Notice that it's only when the call to M3 returns that we hit the await in M2. We also have to wait here so we do almost the same as M3 and return a Task"  i suddently get it all.  "await" is waiting for some meaningful job(it's a task here),so M3 will  print 4&5 and then return a task , the "await" in M2 now get a task to wait,at the meantime it return to M1 ,print the 3,and then again "await" in the M1 return to Main to print 8. After 3 seconds the task in M3 print 6 and fisnish it self,so M2 can contine, print 7.

Comment: Excellent explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It's easiest to see when you look at what this code is actually doing under the hood.  Here's an approximate translation of what that code is doing:

```
public void M1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("STEP:1");
    var t = M2();
    Console.WriteLine("STEP:3");
    t.ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        //do nothing
    });
}
public Task<string> M2()
{
    Console.WriteLine("STEP:2");
    Task<string> task = M3();
    return task.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:7");
        return t.Result;
    });
}
public Task<string> M3()
{
    Console.WriteLine("STEP:4");
    var rs = Task.Run<string>(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);//simulate some work that takes 3 seconds
        Console.WriteLine("STEP:6");
        return "foo";
    });
    Console.WriteLine("STEP:5");
    return rs.ContinueWith(t => t.Result);
}
```

Note that, for the sake of brevity, I've not done proper error handling here.  One of the biggest benefits to using `await` is that it handles errors in the way you generally want them to, and using the tools I have here...doesn't.  This code also doesn't schedule the continuations to use the current synchronization context, something that's irrelevant to this situation, but is a useful feature.

At this point it hopefully is more clear as to what's going on.  For starters, `M1` and `M3` really have no business being `async` in the first place, as they never doing anything meaningful in their continuations.  They should really just not be `async` and to return the tasks they get from calling other methods. `M2` is the only method that actually does anything useful in any of the continuations it creates.

It also makes it clearer as to the order of operations. We call `M1`, which calls `M2`, which calls `M3`, which calls `Task.Run`, then `M3` returns a task that's identical to what `Task.Run` returns and then returns itself, then `M2` adds its continuation and returns, then `M3` executes the next printline, then adds its continuation (which does nothing when it eventually runs), then returns.  Then at some later point in time the `Task.Run` finishes, and all of the continuations run, bottom up (because each is a continuation of the other).

Comment: Thank you @Servy, now I think i should dig it in the TPL to see the detail.