# Using ExecuteStoreQueryAsync inside an Asp.Net Application in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, async-await, entity-framework-6

I have an Asp.Net web forms application and in the `Page_Load event` of my page I have the below code

```
protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     var data = await ChartDataHelper.GetBidsAverageCycle("2018", "Q4",              
                "Fiscal");
      SomeSyncOperation();
  }
```

and here's the main method

```
public static async Task<List<BidAveragceCycleModel>> GetBidsAverageCycle(string year, string quarter, string yearType)
        {
            SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter("@RequestData", BuildMonthsFilter(year, quarter, yearType));
            var data =await Entities.Current.ExecuteStoreQueryAsync<BidAveragceCycleModel>("exec Dashboard_Bids_AverageCycleTime @RequestData"
                 , new[] { parameter1 });
            return data.ToList();
        }
```

I was thinking having `await on the ExecuteStoreQueryAsync will return the control back to Page_Load and call SomeSyncOperation()` but looks like it is running in a `synchronous fashion` and after 10 seconds when the Stored Proc returns data it then calls `data.ToList()` and then only returns back to `Page_Load` call.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused at control flow of async/await of c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706526/confused-at-control-flow-of-async-await-of-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

> after 10 seconds when the Stored Proc returns data it then calls data.ToList() and then only returns back to Page_Load call.

This is how `async`/`await` works.

If you *want* `Page_Load` to finish before loading `data`, then what you can do is store a `Task<List<BidAveragceCycleModel>>` and have the `Page_Load` assign that task variable (without `await`ing it). Then later, when that data is needed, the code can `await` that `Task<T>`.